# has and _belongs_to_many lookup

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I just know I'm gonna kick myself for this one...

I have a Trader model:

```
class Trader < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :locations
end
```

And a Location model:

```
class Location < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :traders
end
```

I have currently created a Class method called in_location:

```
  def self.in_location(location)
    traders_found = []
    traders = Trader.all

    traders.each do |trader|
      locations = trader.locations
        locations.each do |trader_location|
          traders_found << trader if trader_location == location
        end
    end
    traders_found
  end
```

I have a feeling this is all kinds of wrong and Rails can handle this in a one liner.

If so what would the query look like to find all of the traders with a location of X

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can't you just do something like:

```
location = Location.find(1) # or whatever
location.traders
```

?

Seems like you don't even need this `in_location` method at all.

Comment: This is the correct way to do it IF you already have an instance of the class (ie: a `Location` instance). It uses one of the "free" methods you get when you setup a `has_and_belongs_to_many` relationships. If you don't have an instance, then @JorgedelosSantos has the right idea.

Comment: That's it exactly, think I have been looking at this too long.

Comment: PS: @JonleePeakman you may also want to look into "eager loading" so you can query for location/traders in a more optimized way. For example: `location = Location.where(...).includes(:traders)`